# Why ASP.Net adds duplicate records in aspnet_Users table?

Tags: asp.net, roles, membership

I have specified my application name as MyApplication in Web.config in membership provider. 
I have 2 records in aspnet_Applications table: 1. With Application Name as "/" 2. With Application Name as "MyApplication". When I create user through create user wizard or WAT and assign role to that user, ASP.Net adds 2 rows for that user in aspnet_Users table for each ApplicationID in aspnet_Applications table. Table aspnet_Membership has a records for the added user with ApplicationID corresponding to "MyApplication". Also, aspnet_UsersInRoles table has record for newly added user which corresponds with ApplicationID for ApplicationName "/". 
I have tried changing applicationName in web.config from "MyApplication" to "/MyApplication", but got same results. Please let me know whether this is correct behavior or something is wrong. I have browsed through similar questions but found no answer. Hence asking this question.

Comment: Please post the contents of your web.config file.

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name="TestCookie" loginUrl="~/Public/Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" path="/"/>
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="TestProvider">
<providers>
  <clear/>
<add name="TestProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" applicationName="Myapplication" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" requiresUniqueEmail="true"/>
 </providers>
</membership>

Comment: There has to be another place where you are specifying / as your application.

Comment: No I am not. I believe / is the default.

Comment: Are you specifying a RoleProvider elsewhere in your web.config?